# Validate that the username contains letters and numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to validate that the user has letters and numbers
Example:

"pedro123" -> true
"peter" -> false

I have this:

```
function isUserNameValid(username) {
  const res = /(?!.*[\.\-\_]{2,})^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,24}$/.exec(username);
  const valid = !!res;
  return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use several regexps:

```js
function isUserNameValid(username) {
  const hasLetter = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(username);
  const hasNumber = /[0-9]/.test(username);
  const isValid = hasLetter && hasNumber;
  return isValid;
}

console.log(isUserNameValid("pedro123"))
console.log(isUserNameValid("peter"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You were already there. Use *.test* instead of *.exec*
So:

```
function isUserNameValid(username) {
   return /(?!.*[\.\-\_]{2,})^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,24}$/.test(username);
}
```

By the way, this also states that username must be between 3 and 24 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const isUserNameValid = function (userName) {
  let regExp = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])/;
  return regExp.test(userName);
};
```